# Running shiny app hosted on private bitbucket

Tags: r, github, shiny, bitbucket

I am aware of running shiny apps from github as below,

```
library(shiny)    
runGitHub("<private repository name>", "<my user name>")
```

Is there anything similar to run from bitbucket which is restricted to my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runGitHub` and `runGist` are just wrappers around `runUrl`:

> runUrl() downloads and launches a Shiny application that is hosted at a downloadable URL. The Shiny application must be saved in a .zip, .tar, or .tar.gz file.

Therefore, the following will work:

```
shiny::runUrl("https://bitbucket.org/JohnCoene/sigmajshiny/get/d88a6921634d.zip")
```

The link above is taken from:

Repo > Downloads > Download Repository

Comment: I tried this without saving it in a zip file. Now it will work.